# Javascript - How does this preservation of variable works in Closure javascript?

Tags: javascript, closure

```
function outside(x) {
  function inside(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
  return inside;
}
fn_inside = outside(3); //1* -  Think of it like: give me a function that adds 3 to whatever you give it
result = fn_inside(5); //2* - returns 8

result1 = outside(3)(5); // returns 8
```

1*,2* - Since each call provides potentially different arguments, a new closure is created for each call to outside. The memory can be freed only when the returned inside is no longer accessible.

Questions

1) What happens when we call `outside(3)`?

- 1a) What does it return?

2) Is `fn_inside(3);` a valid function call?

3) How is `outside(3)(5)` valid when outside function definition
   accepts only one parameter?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This question doesn't reflect what the site is about. It's not on-topic to ask for an explanation of code that you do not understand. See [What topics can I ask about?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Phrancis - It says what questions should be asked here. But it doesn't say where this kind of question go to . When I go to Stackoverflow, people kick me out there the same way . So I came here and people do the same. Please take this issue seriously and come up with a tabular column or AI to recognise and categorise the question. It would definitely help the community.

Comment: Your question definitely does not fit Code Review, and stack overflow is to help with bugs, hence your question does not fit them either. You could try https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/forum/90-javascript/ but I will warn you your question looks a lot like homework and thus you will have a hard time getting an answer at most sites. You can always open a browser and run the code you have and that will answer your first two questions. And a hint for 3, Its valid because `outside(3)` returns a function that is called with the second `(5)` Its 2 calls, not one call with 2 args

Comment: @Blindman67 Thank you very much for answering. Oh my god. I'm 27 years old and I'm not working on homework. If I add my personal profile details as Engineer, will people help here. I seem to keep facing the issue of posting correct question in correct part of StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `outside(3)` returns a function. Like you said, it returns a function takes one argument `n` and returns `n + 3`. Mathematically, this might be written as *f(n) = n + 3*.
2. `fn_inside` is a binding made to the return value of `outside(3)`, which we know, from part 1, is a function. So when we call `fn_inside(3)`, it's like plugging in 3 for *n*: *f(3) = 3 + 3 = 6*. The return value is simply a number: 6.
3. `outside(3)(5)` is equivalent to `(outside(3))(5)` and recall that `outside(3)` is a function that takes one argument.